# Name for testing routes, controller and views

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, integration-testing, phpunit, testing-framework

I am currently writing tests for my Laravel 5.1 application and testing the workflow: input data from view to route to controller and back to view, typically checking for a DB record and a success/error message using Laravel's PHPUnit interface.

I am trying to categorise my testing types by directory (unit, integration, regression) what test type does the above fall under?

Comment: That one i guess :p. On a serious note you can place that under integration if you like. Or maybe you can come up with some new and innovative term of your own! It's really up to your understanding!

Comment: I was leaning towards integration as it is testing more than one component and it assumes the smallest units are working.

Answer (score 1):

From the 4 quadrants of Agile testing this could be considered to be

Functional Testing (Quadrant 2, top left)

Answer (score 0):

This would fall under the integration category because you are testing multiple components of a system working together. More info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).